# unwanted fancybox-margin class is appended

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I wanted to get rid of the scrollbar on the parent window once I have my fancybox open.

If the overlay locked property is set to true, then the scrollbar is removed. But, an additional class `fancybox-margin` is added to my `<div>`. This is effecting the width of the fancybox.
So i am setting overlay locked property to false. This fixes the width issue, but i see the scrollbar again

My requirement is 
I want to remove the scrollbar from parent window. But the width of the fancybox should not be effected.

Here is my complete code

```
j.fancybox({
    href: "#myDiv",
    autoSize: false,
    autoResize: false,
    padding: 0,
    scrolling: 'no',
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn: false,
    beforeShow: function() {
        j(".fancybox-outer").css("backgroundColor", "transparent");
        this.width = document.getElementById("myDiv").offsetWidth;
        this.height = document.getElementById("myDiv").offsetHeight;
    },
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't give us a lot to work with. A screenshot or a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (even better!) would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: There's no reason to add the `locked:true` helper, the overlay is locked by default.

Comment: Casper: Sorry! I am unable to use fiddle because the response I am getting it dynamic.